# animate back css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I have written the following css animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
    from {
        color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
    }
}
#social .items div:hover span{
    -webkit-animation: shadow 0.4s linear 0.5s 1 alternate;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

you can see the result here: http://mklmb.bplaced.de/page/ (the 3 circles right)
But, when you leave the field of the social box after hovering it, the text color just jumps back to transparent. I want to let it animate back. 
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `transition` ? http://jsbin.com/waxayu/1/edit

```
#social .items div span{
  color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0);
  transition: color 0.4s linear 0s;  /* Fade out immediately on mouseleave */
}
#social .items div:hover span{
  color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
  transition: color 0.4s linear 1s;  /* On hover wait 1s,  than fade in */
}
```

Comment: maybe.. this is an good idea ^^ i didnt knew about the delay attribute of transitions... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**"animation-fill-mode" [forwards/backwards]** is what you are looking for

Usually it will have the same duration than the original but you can set a custom duration like in this example:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
animation-fill-mode: backwards;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
animation-duration: 0s;
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/20awhhwy/